# Creating a string from an array of characters accounting for escape characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, parsing, escaping

I am attempting to write a function that takes an array of characters that make up a string (including the start and end '"') and returns the string that makes up the array.

example input / output:

```
input = ['"', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', '"'];
output = "hello there";
```

or:

EDIT (clarify invalid array example):

```
var str = '"\\\\\\"\\"x\\""'
JSON.parse(str);  // returns "\\"\"x\""
// I want my function to work the same way but after converting the str to an array
var array = str.split("");
```

Right now I have the following:

```
var makeString = function(array){
    var result = "";
    var arr = string.split('');
    var runner = true;
    var i = 1;
    while (arr[i]){
       // This if statement doesn't work, but it is intended to 
       // account for any double quotes inside the string
        if (arr[i] === '"' && arr[i-1] !== '\\'){
            return result;
        }
        result += arr[i];
        i++;
    }
};
```

my function doesn't really work, but I also need it to account for all uses of escape characters and \r \n \t etc (which I don't really understand in the first place).

EDIT / addition:
from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js
I am trying to create something like crockford did to parse a string with the sub function, except I want to take the current state of the input and convert it to an array and parse it through the array elements.

```
    string = function () {

// Parse a string value.

        var hex,
            i,
            string = '',
            uffff;

// When parsing for string values, we must look for " and \ characters.

        if (ch === '"') {
            while (next()) {
                if (ch === '"') {
                    next();
                    return string;
                }
                if (ch === '\\') {
                    next();
                    if (ch === 'u') {
                        uffff = 0;
                        for (i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
                            hex = parseInt(next(), 16);
                            if (!isFinite(hex)) {
                                break;
                            }
                            uffff = uffff * 16 + hex;
                        }
                        string += String.fromCharCode(uffff);
                    } else if (typeof escapee[ch] === 'string') {
                        string += escapee[ch];
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    string += ch;
                }
            }
        }
        error("Bad string");
    },
```

Comment: why don't you use `join` ? .... `input.join("")`

Comment: do you want to covert array to string or string to array?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes [console run](http://screencloud.net/v/Ac3R) ?

Comment: I meant the second case, but I see the problem the array is not well-formed.. the array contains invalid characters

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes yes, the code shown above has many errors ..... array is mal-formed, `string` don't exist, etc, etc ....

Answer (score 0):

To strip out the escape characters, you need to use the string's `replace` function and take in a regex as a parameter

```
function arrayToString(array) {
    return array.join('').replace(/[\\\"]/g, "")
}
```

Test Case

```
var input = ['"', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', '"'];
arrayToString(input)
=> "hello there"
```

Comment: Yes, I just created a function for it.